# How can I extract the number from the output of a shell command?

Tags: perl

The output for the command is `ent3`, and from that output I want `3` to be stored in a variable

#### Perl code

```
            sub {
            if ( $exit == 1 )
           {
            $cmdStr = "lsdev | grep en | grep VLAN | awk '{ print \$1 }'\r";
            $result =_run_cmd($cmdStr);
            my @PdAt_val =    split("\r?\n", $result);
            my $num = $result =~ /([0-9]+)/;
            print "The char is $num\n";
            $exit = 0;
                exp_continue;
```

#### Tidied code

```
sub {

    if ( $exit == 1 ) {

        $cmdStr = "lsdev | grep en | grep VLAN | awk '{ print \$1 }'\r";
        $result = _run_cmd($cmdStr);

        my @PdAt_val = split("\r?\n", $result);

        my $num = $result =~ /([0-9]+)/;
        print "The char is $num\n";

        $exit = 0;

        exp_continue;
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: Hi. Any chance you could re-format your code - removing the line numbers (if that's what they are), fix indentation, etc.?

Comment: This command - lsdev | grep en | grep VLAN | awk '{ print \$1 }'  should produce ent3, which it is doing. After that i want the number  3 from ent3 to be stored in a variable. But i am not able to do that.

Comment: Either this is an anonymous subroutine (which seems ambitious for someone who's asking basic regex questions) or you've retyped the code for our benefit and made some mistakes in the process.

Comment: I have just started and not very familiar with perl, so if anybody can help, please do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code that is doing the work here is:

```
my $num = $result =~ /([0-9]+)/;
```

Let's put that into a simple program so we can see what's going on.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $result = 'ext3';

my $num = $result =~ /([0-9]+)/;

say $num;
```

And that prints `1`. Which isn't what we want. What's going on?

Well, if you read the documentation for the match operator (in the section [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) in "perlop"), you'll see what the operator returns under different circumstances. It says:

> Searches a string for a pattern match, and in scalar context returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails.

So that explains the behaviour we're seeing. That "1" is just a true value saying that the match succeeded. But how do we get the value that we have captured in our parentheses. There are a couple of ways. Firstly, it's written into the `$1` variable.

```
my $num;

if ($result =~ /([0-9]+)/) {
  $num = $1;
}

say $num;
```

But I think the other approach is what you were looking for. If you read on, you'll see what the operator returns in list context:

> `m//` in list context returns a list consisting of the subexpressions matched by the parentheses in the pattern, that is, (`$1`, `$2`, `$3` ...)

So if we put the match operator in list context, then we'll get the contents of `$1` returned. How do we put a match into list context? By making the expression a list assignment - which we can do by putting parentheses around the left-hand side of the assignment.

```
my ($num) = $result =~ /([0-9]+)/;

say $num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, something like this should work:

```
if($result =~ /([0-9]+)/) {
    $num = $1;
}
print $num;
```